# Why is this promise resolving early?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

The promise from Product.find() is resolving before the loop updating the highest price has completed. How can I resolve the promise only when the data manipulation is complete?

```
Product.find({'prodType': req.params.type}).lean().exec(function (err, product) {

    if (err) {
        res.status(400);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {

        (function(u) {

            Option.find({'prodId': product[i].productId}).lean().sort({price: -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, highest) {

                product[u].price = highest;
                // not updated in returned object

            });

        })(i);

    }

}).then(function (product) {

    res.send(product);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all of the code from the `.exec()` callback to a `.then`, and return a new promise to it that resolves when all the other promises are complete.

```
Product.find({'prodType': req.params.type}).lean().exec()
.then(function (product) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {

        (function(u) {

            promises.push(Option.find({'prodId': product[i].productId}).lean().sort({price: -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, highest) {

                product[u].price = highest;
                // not updated in returned object

            }));

        })(i);

    }
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        // we want to pass the original product array to the next .then
        return product; 
    });

}).then(function (product) {

    res.send(product);

}).catch(function (err) { // the power of promise error catching!
    // If any error occurs in any of the db requests or in the code, this will be called.
    res.status(400);
});
```

Also, since you're dealing with an array, .map makes this easier and removes the need for the inner IIFE.

```
Product.find({'prodType': req.params.type}).lean().exec()
.then(function (product) {
    var promises = product.map(function (p) {
        return Option.find({'prodId': p.productId}).lean().sort({price: -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, highest) {

            p.price = highest;

        }));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        // we want to pass the original product array to the next .then
        return product; 
    });

}).then(function (product) {

    res.send(product);

}).catch(function (err) { // the power of promise error catching!
    // If any error occurs in any of the db requests or in the code, this will be called.
    res.status(400);
});
```